# How to prevent RethinkDB from creating test database

Tags: javascript, database, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

When you launch a rethinkdb instance, it will automatically create a database called 'test'. When you run multiple instances and cluster them using `rethinkdb proxy` this leads to the issue:

`Database name conflict: test is the name of more than one database`

If you try to delete the databases i.e using

```
r.dbDrop('test').run(conn, function(result) {
   console.log(result) // Will result in error
});
```

This will produce the following error:

`ReqlOpFailedError: Database 'test' is ambiguous; there are multiple databases with that name in r.dbDrop("test")`

So how to prevent RethinkDB from creating the 'test' database automatically? Or how to remove a database if you run into name conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `rethinkdb create` to create a data directory, no `test` database will be created.

For example, if `rethinkdb_data` doesn't exist, this will create it with no `test` database:

```
rethinkdb create
rethinkdb
```

This will do the same, but uses `-d` to specify the location of the data directory:

```
rethinkdb create -d /var/lib/rethinkdb/data
rethinkdb -d /var/lib/rethinkdb/data
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this did not yield the results described--the `test` database was still created.

Comment: It worked for me using RethinkDB v2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

After digging for a while I didn't find any good options to prevent RethinkDB from trying to create the default `test` database on startup. The problem above only occurs when the cluster nodes use different data directories. Otherwise they will not try to create extra `test` databases as the other nodes will simply recognise it already exists (created by the first node that launched).

I ended up solving this in my backend software by enumerating all database named `test` during startup from the `db_config` table in `rethinkdb` database.

Example:

```
// Read from the database 'rethinkdb' that holds information about other databases
r.db("rethinkdb")

// Table db_config contains database id, name information
 .table("db_config")

// Filter by name 'test'
 .filter({name: "test"})
 .run(conn, function(err, cursor) {

     // Get results from cursor by id and rename
     cursor.each(function(err, result){
         r.db("rethinkdb")
          .get(result.id)
          .update({name: "other_name"})
          .run(conn, function(err, result) {
              console.log(result.replaced);
           });
     });
});
```